# ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

in my app i am using a listview to display a menu of dishes with their Dish Names

This is the code where i bind the data from the query to the listview using the adapter:

```
private void getDishes() {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllDishes();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.w("ppp","kk - " + cursor.moveToFirst());
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[] { DBAdapter.DishName },
            new int[] {R.id.dishName });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
}
```

My Query code looks like this:

```
public Cursor getAllDishes()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {DishName},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Really appreciate any help/comments as i have been stuck on this for almost a week now.

Comment: I didn't read the code, as you might need to improve your question. What's the problem and what's causing you to get stuck?

Comment: check this tutorial over Listview: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add, the app doesnt seem to be able to run using the codes in the 1st post, i did a logcat to check whether the query is working and it returns true, this means the value is null right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain explicitely what's your problem?

My suggest change

```
    public Cursor getAllDishes()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {DishName},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

to

```
    public Cursor getAllDishes()
    {
    Cursor dishes = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {DishName},null,null,null,null,null);
if(dishes != null)
dishes.moveToFirst();
        return dishes;
    }
```

Then

in `getDishes()` method write like this

```
private void getDishes() {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllDishes();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(YourActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[] { DBAdapter.DishName },
            new int[] {R.id.dishName });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
}
```